# How to run only tests marked with a specific feature and ignoring the rest?

Tags: rust

If there is a test module as following,

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests{

    #[test]
    #[cfg(feature="turbo")]
    fn test1(){}

    #[test]
    fn test2(){}

    #[test]
    fn test3(){}

}
```

I want to run only tests marked with feature turbo and ignore the rest. Is this scenario possible?

I tried running cargo test with

```
--features "turbo"
```

but that runs all the tests instead of a single test.

Answer (score 2):

In Rust, when you use conditional compilation attributes like `#[cfg(feature="turbo")]`, it means that the code block will only be compiled and included in the binary if the specified feature is enabled. However, when you run tests with cargo test `--features "turbo"`, it enables the turbo feature for the entire crate, not just for specific tests. That's why all tests are being run in your case, including those without the turbo feature tag.

To achieve what you're looking for, you can use a combination of features and test filtering. Here's how you can do it:

1. Use a unique test function prefix: Name your tests with the `turbo`
   feature with a unique prefix. For instance, you could name them
   `turbo_test1`, `turbo_test2`, etc.
2. Filter tests during execution: When you run `cargo test`, you can
   filter which tests to run by passing a part of the test name as an
   argument.

Given your scenario, you would modify your tests like this:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    #[cfg(feature="turbo")]
    fn turbo_test1() {}

    #[test]
    fn test2() {}

    #[test]
    fn test3() {}
}
```

Then, to run only the tests with the turbo feature enabled, you would execute the following command:

```bash
cargo test --features "turbo" -- turbo_test
```

This command will run all tests that have `turbo_test` in their name and are compiled with the `turbo` feature enabled. Since `test2` and `test3` do not have `turbo_test` in their names, they will be ignored.